# Jersey Provider is not getting Context programmatically

Tags: java, web-services, jersey, jax-rs

I have REST webservices being brought up in Jersey programmatically and I need it to wrap a call to a 2PP Provider for AuthN/AuthZ purposes. The problem is that the 2PP Provider is not able to resolve the @Context. I have provided below a sample snippet of what code is being done.

**Provider that needs to be integrated**:

```
package com.fctest.restful.hello.provider;

@Component (immediate = true)
@javax.ws.rs.ext.Provider
public class MyDummyProvider
{
    @Context
    protected javax.inject.Provider<ContainerRequestContext> containerRequestContextProvider;
    //The above var is NULL causing calls to fail for this class.
}
```

**My Webservice code**:

```
@Activate
public void activate(BundleContext bctx)
{
    registerServlet(bctx);
    registerDummyResource();
    packages("com.fctest.restful.hello.provider");
    myContainer.reload(this);
}

private void registerServlet(BundleContext bctx)
{
    try
    {
        HttpService httpService = bctx.getService(bctx.getServiceReference(HttpService.class));
        Dictionary<String, String> jerseyServletParams = new Hashtable<String, String>();
        jerseyServletParams.put("javax.ws.rs.Application", NoAnnotateRest.class.getName());
        httpService.registerServlet("/services", myContainer, jerseyServletParams, null);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        LOG.error("Exception occurred registering servlet: ", e);
    }
}

private void registerDummyResource()
{
    final Resource.Builder resourceBuilder = Resource.builder();
    resourceBuilder.path("/hello2");

    final ResourceMethod.Builder methodBuilder = resourceBuilder.addMethod("GET");
    methodBuilder
            .produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN_TYPE)
            .handledBy(new Inflector<ContainerRequestContext, String>()
            {
                @Override
                public String apply(ContainerRequestContext containerRequestContext)
                {
                    return "Hello World!";
                }
            });

    registerResources(resourceBuilder.build());
}
```

I also tried below and got the following error:

```
@Activate
public void activate(BundleContext bctx)
{
    registerServlet(bctx);
    registerDummyResource();
    packages("com.fctest.restful.hello.provider");
    register(MyDummyProvider.class);
    myContainer.reload(this);
}
```

> 2017-06-01 17:03:45,025 | WARN  | raf-3.0.7/deploy | Providers
>   | 75 - org.glassfish.jersey.core.jersey-common - 2.17.0 | A provider
>   com.fctest.restful.hello.provider.MyDummyProvider registered in SERVER
>   runtime does not implement any provider interfaces applicable in the
>   SERVER runtime. Due to constraint configuration problems the provider
>   com.fctest.restful.hello.provider.MyDummyProvider will be ignored.

Answer (score 0):

In my Spring-Boot app I faced a similar Warning, Solution was to not register the `object` but `object.getClass()`.

in your case, I would replace

```
registerResources(resourceBuilder.build());
```

with

```
register(resourceBuilder.build().getClass());
```